# wyswyg insert into jquery form

Tags: jquery, textarea

I have multiple jquery forms with textarea:

```
$('#admin_content_product_info_en').text(data['info_en']).val(data['info_en']);
$('#admin_content_product_info_de').text(data['info_de']).val(data['info_de']);
$('#admin_content_product_info_ru').text(data['info_ru']).val(data['info_ru']);
```

in this case i got textarea with text what i can edit, when i try replace textarea with WYSWYG editor, with next function

```
$("textarea").htmlarea(
    {
toolbar: [ "bold", "italic", "underline" ]     
    });
```

i got textarea what replaced with editor, but text absent in text field. If i switch off this function, i got regular textarea with text. How correctly insert  editor and insert text in this fields with WYSWYG ?

Thanks !

Comment: add the function before inserting the text

Comment: this function placed before inserting text and i got empty fields

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: firefox, google chrome

Comment: in chrome, open developers tools-> Console->All. Is there any error?

Comment: sorry for long answer, no. any error in console, just still empty fields when i switch to replace textarea with jHtmlEditor

Comment: why not always have a jHtmlEditor instead of switching midway?

Comment: then use something like: `$('#textAreaID').val(data['info_en']).htmlarea('updateHtmlArea');` to set your html.